# how to remove first two characters in object array using lodash

Tags: typescript, lodash

This question might be simple! I am working in an angular project. Consider my array format is like below.

```
 "dataItem": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "caption": "01   Data One"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "caption": "02   Data Two"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "caption": "03   Data Three"
    }   
]
```

In the caption property, I want to strip off first two characters (i.e. 01, 02, 03). So, the caption would be something similar like below

```
"dataItem": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "caption": "Data One"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "caption": "Data Two"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "caption": "Data Three"
    }   
]
```

Is there a way to use lodash to write one or two lines of code to achieve this? I tried other resources, but could not get vertical slices in a simple way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work,

```
const lodash = require('lodash')

const data = {
  "dataItem": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "caption": "01   Data One"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "caption": "02   Data Two"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "caption": "03   Data Three"
    }   
]
}

const result = lodash.map(data.dataItem, item => {
  // substring from 5 because number and spaces seem to end at fifth position
  return { ...item, caption: item.caption.substring(5) }
})
```

Comment: This works like charm! Thanks @Sandeep. Instead of substring(5), I used substring(2).trim(). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla JS to do that.

```
for (item of dataItem) {
  item.caption = item.caption.substring(2).replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, "");
}
console.log(dataItem);
```

If you really want to use lodash, it would look something like this (not tested)

```
_.forEach(dataItem, function(item) {
  item.caption = item.caption.substring(2).replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/g, "");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @SeekerDK. Unfortunately, I am getting the error when I tried to assign caption property: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'caption' of object '[object Object]'" using vanilla JS. checking on that. appreciate your swift response. Its useful.